# await a `dispatch` in order to hide a modal box with `setState`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been working in a react application that uses redux to maintain states globally. But in a particular component, I intentionally mixed `setState` with `dispatch` calls. I just used `setState` to hide/show modal container and dispatch for doing a network operation. Here is a sample code:

```
onButtonClick = () => { 
 this.setState({ showAddModal: true });
}

onButtonInModalClick = data => {
 this.props.dispatchSave(data);
 this.setState({ showAddModal: false });
};
```

Now, the problem is `setState` is not waiting for the `dispatchSave` to get completed. I even tried using `await this.props.dispatchSave(data);`. No luck with that. My question here is, Can't we mix up setState with dispatch when doing an asynchronous operation? If yes why? If no, what is wrong with my approach?

summary of what I am trying:

- there is a button available, on clicking it, a modal will be opened using setState.
- Inside the modal there is a button available, on clicking it, it saves data via dispatch
- after performing the operation, again setState will be used to close the modal.

Code used for async action:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatchSave(data) {
    dispatch(actions.save(data));
  }
});

//---------- Above is from the component file

save(data) {
 return async dispatch => {
  await httpSrc.save(data);
  dispatch(actions.setData({ data: [] }));
 };
},
```

Comment: How are you performing the async operation? Thunk/Middleware/Saga/etc...

Comment: @OriDrori using redux-thunk.

Comment: Please add the async action (`dispatchSave`) to the question.

Comment: @OriDrori I just updated the question. Can you please check?

Comment: You need your own promise, read this article: https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/returning-promises-from-redux-action-creators-3035f34fa74b

Comment: I saw examples : https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk, It seems ```dispatch``` is or can be a promise, hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the `mapDispatchToProps` that doesn't return generated by the async action.

Define `mapDispatchToProps` [as an object](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object). It's a shorter way to bind with dispatch, and it will pass on the promise returned from the thunk:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { dispatchSave: actions.save };
```

Now you can await the dispatch:

```
onButtonInModalClick = async data => {
  await this.props.dispatchSave(data);
  this.setState({ showAddModal: false });
};
```

I would also return the `data` from the action, so it will be available when awaiting the thunk (if needed):

```
save(data) {
  return async dispatch => {
    await httpSrc.save(data);

    dispatch(actions.setData({ data: [] }));

    return data;
  };
},
```

Comment: **The main problem is the mapDispatchToProps that doesn't return generated by the async action.** What do you mean by this? Should I change my code something like this? `dispatchSave(data) {
    return dispatch(actions.save(data));
  }`

Comment: You can if you want to, but just use this `const mapDispatchToProps = { dispatchSave: actions.save };` (look at the link I've added to get more info).

Comment: plus1 for the link. I didn't notice it. Let me read it and come back.